# Dlib linear svr-SVM detection - setting typenames

Tags: c++, object-detection, dlib

I want to train svr linear svm ( I hope so doing well), but I have problem with set the typename(s) for variables in detection. Any information would be great.

Features were extracted by Hog compute from openCV.

```
void TrainFHog::train(cv::Mat trainMat, std::vector<int> labels) try
    {
        typedef dlib::matrix < double, 1980, 1 > sample_type;
        typedef dlib::linear_kernel< sample_type > kernel_type;
        std::vector < sample_type > samples;
        std::vector < double > flLabels;
        dlib::svr_linear_trainer< kernel_type > trainer;

        for (int y = 0; y < trainMat.rows; y++) {
            sample_type samp;

            for (int x = 0; x < trainMat.cols; x++) {
                double val = 0.0;
                val = trainMat.at<float>(y, x);
                samp(x) = val;

            }
            samples.push_back(samp);
            flLabels.push_back(labels[y]);
        }

        std::cout << "All samples : " <<  samples.size() << std::endl;

        typedef dlib::probabilistic_decision_function<kernel_type> probabilistic_funct_type;
        typedef dlib::normalized_function<probabilistic_funct_type> pfunct_type;
        pfunct_type learned_pfunct;
        trainer.set_epsilon(0.001);
        trainer.set_c(0.01054);

        //learned_pfunct.function = train_probabilistic_decision_function(trainer, samples, flLabels, 3);
        auto trained = trainer.train(samples, flLabels);
        dlib::serialize("traind.svm") << trained;
    //  dlib::serialize("pfunct.svm") << learned_pfunct.function.decision_funct;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```